# eigenvalue of diagonal and symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

i have a matrix of the form

$K=(diag(CAC^{-1}\mathbf{1}))^{-1}A$

where $C,A,K \in R^{n \times n}$, $C$ is diagonal with $c_{ii}>1$ and $\mathbf{1} \in R^{n \times 1}$ represents the vector of ones.

$A$ is a binary symmetric matrix $(a_{ij}=0,~1)$ but the diagonal elements $a_{ii}=1$, also $A=A^T$.

Can anyone help me in proving that maximum eigenvalue of $K$ is $1$ ?

The $diag(CAC^{-1}\mathbf{1})$ creates a diagonal matrix containing the row-sum of $CAC^{-1}$.